# Authentication.Challenge not working with ApiController

Tags: single-sign-on, .net-framework-version, asp.net-apicontroller, owin-middleware, owin-security

With ApiController, Authentication.Challenge not prompting Microsoft login for SSO. it executes SignIn action method, with out any errors. If I change from ApiController to **Controller** then it's prompting. does any one know how to prompt for Microsoft login using ApiController?

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/values/signin")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}  


public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    public void SignIn()
    {
        if (!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can some one reply.it helps my job.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced a similar problem on our product.

The issue was the following: `Challenge` sets `401` status code for current response, which is later handled by a responsible OWIN Middleware, so if status code is not `401` the middleware won't handle the response and won't trigger the redirect.

But the default behavior of `void` action of `ApiController` sets `204` response status code. Therefore `401` is overwritten with `204`, as a result nothing happens.

So there are several solutions:

1. Don't use `ApiController` if you can
2. Use `ApiController` but not `void` action. Use for example something like this

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(...);
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Response.StatusCode);
}
```

3. If you have to use a `void` method and `ApiController` then you can end the response and then the status code won't be modified.

```
public void SignIn()
{
    HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(...);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```